# Taskbar Pinned Shortcuts Location

Tags: windows, taskbar, shortcuts, pinning

Ever wondered where those pinned shortcuts are stored in Win7/8/8.1/10? This way you can edit, delete or create new shortcuts. Sometimes they get duplicated but they don't appear as pinned so this is the only way to delete them.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just need to access this location from explorer:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ben/archive/2009/10/01/taskbar-pinned-shortcuts-location.aspx

Comment: In Windows 8.1 it is in C:\Users\myusername\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` - and can be used to move them to another user login.

Comment: For anyone searching through explorer, %APPDATA% is the Roaming folder, not the Local folder.

Comment: This doesn't include apps installed from the Store. Any idea how to find\edit them?